# Show that $(\det A)x_i=0$ whenever $A \mathbf{x}=0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

I'm working through problem $11.4.3$ in Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* and I've gotten stuck. The problem is as follows:

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, and let $V$ be an $R$-module. Let $A=(a_{ij}) \in M_{n \times n}(R)$ and suppose $x_1,x_2,...,x_n \in V$. Show that if 
>   $$ A \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n \end{bmatrix}=0$$ 
>   then $(\operatorname{det}A)x_i=0$ for all $1\le i \leq n$.

My plan to approach this problem is to somehow interpret each $x_i$ as elements in a ring and then apply Cramer's rule.

For example, the module $N= \langle x_1,...,x_n \rangle $ is finitely generated and hence is isomorphic to a quotient of the form $R^n/M$. So the equation $A\mathbf{x}=0$, where $\mathbf{x}$ is the vector as above, turns into $B=0$, where the entries of $B \in M_{n\times 1} (R^n/M)$ are $b_k= \sum_j a_{kj}x_j$.

Thinking of the ring action on $N$ as ring multiplication in $R^n/M$ we get a relation
$$\sum_i x_i A_i=0,$$
where $A_i$ are the columns of $A$ (note for this to make sense we have to think of an element $a_{ij}$ of the matrix $A$ as the equivalence class of $(a_{ij},...,a_{ij})$ in $R^n/M$). By Cramer's rule we get $x_i\operatorname{det} A=0$ for all $x_i$. Since $R$ is commutative we get that $(\operatorname{det}A)x_i=0$ in $N \subseteq V$.

Am I on the right track? I'm not sure if there's a simpler way to do it, but all the easier methods I've thought of require $R$ to be an integral domain or $V$ to be finitely generated itself.

Comment: Multiply by the classical adjoint of $A$ on the left, and recall that $A^*A=(\det A)I_n$.

Comment: @user26857 Right, I didn't read that far into the chapter but I just found it. Thanks!